# How to notify the user when new message arrives to inbox of the specific application in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, sms

I want to notify users of the application(**which might not currently be running in the foreground**) when new message arrives to that specific port. can anyone tell how to do that & any example?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html. Status Bar Notifications can be used for this purpose. There are also code examples to start with.

Another approach would be using Toast Notifications (see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html).

Both notification types can be used even if the associated application is in the background.